# Accessing JSON within jtable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-jtable

I'm new to the jQuery jTable plugin. Consider [this snippet from an official sample](http://www.jtable.org/demo/masterchild)

```
Phones: {
title: '',
width: '5%',
sorting: false,
edit: false,
create: false,
display: function (studentData) {
...
...
title: studentData.record.Name + ' - Phone numbers',

actions: {
listAction: '/Demo/PhoneList?StudentId=' + studentData.record.StudentId,
```

Why is it that while accessing the JSON, `record` is in lower case -

```
studentData.record.StudentId
```

whereas this is sent from the ASP.NET MVC Controller code -

```
....
    return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = students, TotalRecordCount = studentCount });
....
```

and the JSON that is sent looks like this -

```
{"Result" : "OK", Records : [{"StudentId":1 .... }], TotalRecordCount=5 }
```

My question is how does the code in the sample work when StudentId is accessed as

```
studentData.record.StudentId
```

whereas the regular way to access JSON data is this based on the JSON above that is actually emitted -

```
studentData.Record.StudentId
```

Why does it return `undefined` when I try to access `studentData.Record.TotalRecordCount` or `studentData.record.TotalRecordCount`.

How can I access the value of TotalRecordCount in JavaScript? Can I add custom JSON variables (other than Result, Records, TotalRecordCount) & access their values?

Comment: You are not posting all the code, I can guessing that studentData is an iterator on the Students enumeration.  Post the full code sample please.

Comment: The full sample is here - http://www.jtable.org/demo/masterchild

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for the same thing to place the count inside a tab when data is loaded.
Just came across this:
https://github.com/hikalkan/jtable/issues/169
About halfway down I noticed they referenced 'data.serverResponse'

I tried the following code which worked:

```
"recordsLoaded": function (event,data) {
    $('#tab').html("Items ("+data.serverResponse.TotalRecordCount+")");
}
```

So, looks like you can access the raw JSON through data.serverResponse.